# haskell putStr outputs extra newlines

Tags: haskell, io

```
main = do
       file_name <- getLine
       text <- readFile file_name
       let b = prepare $ line text
       let x = sth b
       mapM_ (putStr . print_matrix . fst ) x
```

When I ran this code I got:

> 1 2 3
>
> 4 5 6
>
> 7 8 9
>
> 9 2 1
>
> 1 1 1
>
> 1 1 1

But in random lines I got extra newlines. When I wrote 300 lines I got 2 extra random newlines.

> 9 2 1
>
> (extra enter)
>
> 1 1 1
>
> 1 1 1

Comment: Maybe one or more of your functions is buggy.  It is hard to tell more from the little information you provided.

Comment: i delete "\n" and putStrLn. I think it is because winghci and ghci have diffrent buffor.

Comment: Not sure if it would make any difference, but does your input file have consistent line endings? Any stray \r characters?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure `putStr` is printing the newlines read in from the file, unless `prepare` or `sth` is chopping them off.